# How to display Listbox conversions in C#?

Tags: c#, listbox, type-conversion

I am supposed to write a code for school that converts inches to feet, feet to yards, etc. This is done by selecting one or the other from two listboxes: a "from" and "two."

However, I am completely stumped on how to do such. I have tried out the code listed below, but other than that I have zero clue.

I want to basically take two values from a listbox, assign it a method based by what was selected in the listbox, and convert it from the user's input. I need some help!

```
namespace Distance_Converter
{
    public partial class frmDistanceConverter : Form
    {
        int inches = 1;
        int feet = 12;
        int yards = 36;

        public frmDistanceConverter()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double feettoInch = feet / 12 * 12;
            double feettoYard = feet / 3;          // feet conversions
            double feettoFeet = feet;

            double yardtoYard = yards;
            double yardtoInch = yards / 1;         // yard conversions
            double yardtoFeet = yards / 12;

            double inchtoYard = inches / 36;
            double inchtoInch = inches;
            double inchtoFeet = inches / 12;

            double totalConversion = double.Parse(txtDistance.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to break this into separate tasks, and finish one task at a time. Your first task is to get the user input for the value to convert, and get the conversion types from the listboxes (you need two of them). Once you've got that done, work on doing the math to do the conversion, using the information you've gotten from the user to decide what you need to do. Then figure out how to display the results.

Comment: So, to be clear you have a box with a value in it, say 36, and you click on a listbox item, say inches to denote the input and then click another list box with expected output, say feet, then click a button to complete it, to get 3 feet? LIke Google convert (https://www.google.co.uk/search?newwindow=1&ei=_q-pW6WOIcqegAbs7pOYBQ&q=google+convert+inches+to+feet&oq=google+convert+inches+to+feet&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i22i30k1.3893.6461.0.6673.15.15.0.0.0.0.86.942.15.15.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.15.941...0i67k1.0.4W4owY8OUA8)

Comment: I Agree with @KenWhite, forget the graphical interface at first. I think a good start is to create a simple method that will take as input what you may have later. give number values to your different options(for example inches is 1, feet is 2 and yard is 3. then try to fill the method having this signature: public double Convert(uint fromUnitVal, uint toUnitVal, int valueToConvert) {...}